# How the url should be stored in records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a question.

I have comment model, in which it has body column that users can type anything in there.
obviously user might type the url link to other website.
In my guess, I think it should be replaced with **< a href >** tag when it is being saved.
Is there any good gem or something to handle this kind of thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use a full-blown markdown parser ([Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet)), use [Rinku](https://github.com/vmg/rinku). It's super fast and *safe*. Do not use any regex based solutions as you would most likely open yourself to security risks.

```
text = "Hello! Check this out: https://github.com/vmg/rinku"
Rinku.auto_link(text, mode=:all, link_attr=nil, skip_tags=nil)
```

Produces:

```
=> "Hello! Check this out: <a href=\"https://github.com/vmg/rinku\">https://github.com/vmg/rinku</a>"
```

Comment: Glad to learn about rinku.  Much better approach than what I suggested/have done in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Preserving for posterity's sake, but I feel it's important to note that this is NOT a secure way to solve the problem.  Unless you want to figure out all the security implications for yourself, don't follow this advice.  Jiří Pospíšil's answer is better. =D

You don't really need a gem to do that (I personally try to avoid gems for something so simple).  Write a regular expression that is reasonably reliable for your purposes, and then use something like

`input.gsub(regex, '<a href="\1">some text</a>')`

to convert the links into their html equivalent.  Note that you'll need to use `raw` to display the results of this, otherwise rails will escape the output for you.  This also means users will be able to put other arbitrary markup in, unless you escape it as it goes into the database.  Make sure you do that.

Alternately, you could do the same thing as you display it, with slightly different considerations/steps necessary.

Comment: (Alternately, you could use the link helper in the second argument of that string.  Doesn't matter too much, it's a matter of preference, I think.)

Comment: **params[:body]** what if you had body like this, how could you replace?

Comment: input is just a placeholder.  You could put params[:body] in it's place.

That being said, Jiří Pospíšil brings up a good point: there are definitely potential security risks with my suggestion.  Don't know why I didn't think of that from the beginning.